# Chat not enough rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

So, on Stack Overflow I can chat (35 reputation points).

On site [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) I could chat before as I had a lot of reputation points because of Stack Overflow.

But on Stack Exchange meta I can't chat despite Stack Overflow and Puzzling!

I even tested this out with site [3D printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour), and I can chat even though I just created an account.

Is there something wrong with Stack Exchange meta chat or everything else's chat?

Screenshots:

[image: Chat screenshot]

[image: User page]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three separate chat galaxies in this chat universe:

1. **Stack Overflow Chat** requires you to have at least 20 reputation points on Stack Overflow.
2. **Stack Exchange Chat** requires you to have at least 20 reputation points on *any Q&A site*, including Stack Overflow.
3. **Meta Stack Exchange Chat** requires you to have at least 20 reputation points on Meta Stack Exchange.

Once you earn at least 200 points on any site, this distinction becomes less important; you get an immediate 100-point "association bonus" on every site, so unless you lose a lot of rep somewhere you'll be able to chat everywhere.